# my icon is corrupted when the app run on the phone?

Tags: java, android, imageview, icons

I'm trying to import a (`25x25 BMP 32-bit color`) to an `ImageView`. The icon is in good state in `android studio preview`. but when I run the app on my phone, the icon seems like it got `corrupted`!
The images in the attachment shows when the icon is displayed on android studio and on my 
phone so you can see the difference.

and this is the xml code for my imageView:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Gry.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyTYp.png

Comment: Does it work if you use a PNG image instead of a Bitmap?